# How to connect to a WebSocket topic using RxJS webSocket?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I have a WebSocket server made in Spring Boot.

This is my WebSocketConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/game-updates");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/game");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

GameController class:

```
@RestController
public class GameController {

    @MessageMapping("/test")
    @SendTo("/game-updates/test-res")
    public Greeting greeting(String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("msg received: " + msg);
        String msgg = "Hello there: " + msg;
        
        return new Greeting(msgg);
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to, listen and send data to this WebSocket using StompJs:

```
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws'
});

stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/game-updates/test-res', (greeting) => {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
       
    });
};

function connect() {
    stompClient.activate();
}

function sendData() {
    stompClient.publish({
        destination: "/game/test",
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'data': $("#data").val() })
    });
}
```

How to do same using RxJs `webSocket`?

I attempted to connect to the WebSocket server using the following code in my Angular app:

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-screen',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './game-screen.component.html',
  styleUrl: './game-screen.component.css',
  imports: [MainMenuComponent, OptionsComponent, GameBoardComponent, ChatComponent, BoardUpdatesComponent, MatProgressSpinnerModule]
})
export class GameScreenComponent implements OnInit {
connectToServer() {
  console.log("connecting to server");
  let url: string = "ws://localhost:8080/ws";
  this.webSocket = webSocket(url);
  this.webSocket.subscribe("/game-updates/test-res", {
    next: (data: any) => {
      console.log('data from server received:');
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: (err: any) => {
      console.log(err)
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('complete');
    }
  });

  this.webSocket.next({
    destination: "/game/test",
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'data': "Hello server" })
  });
}
}
```

While this successfully connects to the WebSocket URL, I am not receiving or able to send any data.

Comment: First time see string as a first argument in subscribe function. Are you sure it should work? I think you should use the whole url to create web socket and use common subscribe syntax with one object or few callbacks.

Comment: Could you please give an example?  
by whole url do you mean:
`url = "ws://localhost:8080/ws/game-updates/test-res";`
I tried this but it did not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Comment section is to small so here is example which should work considering your configuration:

```
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class GameScreenComponent implements OnInit {
  webSocket: WebSocketSubject<any>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.connectToServer();
  }

  connectToServer() {
    const url = 'ws://localhost:8080/ws';
    this.webSocket = webSocket(url);
    this.webSocket.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('Data from server received:', data);
      }
    );
    this.sendDataToServer();
  }

  sendDataToServer() {
    const message = {
      destination: '/game/test',
      body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'Hello server' })
    };

    this.webSocket.next(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not working; neither am I able to send any data nor am I receiving any data from the server. I am using STOMP over WebSocket on my server side. Could that be the reason?

Comment: it is possible. Chrome devtools allows you explore the sockets too, so check how the connection looks like and what data comes via the socket.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the connection was successfully created, and it is showing data sent on the message tab. However, no data is being received on the server.

Comment: Sorry, the only difference I see is that my solution don't provide filtering function for the socket on received messages, but that must send you more messages in respopses. But if your server doesn't even get it, I don't know what is the reason. To debug the problem I can recomend to make the connection and sending messages on some user event (like click on the button) to see if there is some connection problems like CORS for example.  Maybe the problem with trying to do async things in sync code, etc.